# How load on double-click instead of click for magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, magnific-popup

I thought this would be a very simple problem: How to override Magnific Popup's  default method of loading: Instead of loading images on click, I want to load on double-click.

I'm using the module to load images on a site. This is the js code for the page:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // override magnificPopup.resizeImage:
    $.magnificPopup.instance.resizeImage = betterResizeImage;

    var magnific = $('#photoList').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'img', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
    });

    $.getJSON('/json', function(json) {
        console.log('got json');
        json.forEach(function(item) {
            var img=$('<img/>')
                .attr('src', '/img/' + item.thumbnail)
                .attr('class', 'thumnail')
                .attr('data-mfp-src', '/img/' + item.file_name)
                .on('load', function() {
                    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                        console.log('error loading ' + item.thumbnail);
                    } else {
                        $('#photoList').append(img);
                    }            
                });
        });
    });
});
```

`$('#photoList')` is just a div that holds images that get appended to it after page load. All I'm trying to do is change free up the single-click event for something else and instead have Magnific Popup open on double-click.

I can't figure out where in the module's code the onclick event is registered to open the module and how I would overwrite it. Mosh Feu's answer is close, but it results in the first image within the div being opened each time any of the images are double-clicked.

Magnific Popup on Github:
https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup

Comment: Will your users understand this change to established user interface interaction?

Comment: PS: The click handlers are overwritten in the fastclick plugin

Comment: It will better if you will add you code. People will be able to edit your code and provide a solution quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to remove the `click` handler and add double click (`dblclick`) event.

```js
// init magnific
var magnific = $('.magnific').magnificPopup({
  type: 'iframe'
});

// remove click handler of magnific
magnific.off('click');

// prevent the default click event of the link so it will no redirect to the `href`
magnific.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

// add double click handler and call the `open` function of magnific
magnific.on('dblclick', function(){
  magnific.magnificPopup('open')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a class="magnific" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ij_0p_6qTss" class="magnific">magnific</a>
```

**Update**

If you want to show a gallery, that's the way:

```js
// init magnific
var magnific = $('.container').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
  type: 'image',
  gallery:{
    enabled:true
  }
});

var links = magnific.find('a');

// remove click handler of magnific
magnific.off('click');

// prevent the default click event of the link so it will no redirect to the `href`
links.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

// add double click handler and call the `open` function of magnific with a specific index
links.on('dblclick', function() {
  magnific.magnificPopup('open', links.index(this))
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

img {
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <a href="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/objects/general/pics/sun0824.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/objects/general/sun0824_small.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/objects/general/pics/sunobject.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/objects/general/sunobject_small.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/objects/general/pics/sun0824a.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/objects/general/sun0824a_small.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/cusixax/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: It looks like this code actually results in the first image in '#photoList' being displayed each time any image within the div is opened.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to show a gallery, not a single resource (image etc). If so, look the update in my answer. I was added a gallery snippet.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using the gallery mode in this situation. I just want each image to load individually as a standalone image. Either way, the changes you mode are more or less working for me -- the only issue I'm having now is that the 'links' variable is not getting set because the images load asynchronously, but I will get that working no problem. Thanks, this is very helpful!

Comment: My pleasure. If you have any issue with this, please comment and I will try to help you.